# Is there a way to hide Status Bar as soon as the Drawer opens in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to hide the status bar as soon as the drawer opens just like the google maps app on iOS.

Also, can I change the height of drawer header? Right now it's taking a third of the drawer itself.

Cheers